# "The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available" message in IE7 after jQuery AJAX timeout

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, internet-explorer-7, timeout

I've seen bits and pieces of this problem documented around, but no clear solution. I'm making an asynchronous ajax call, using jQuery's $.ajax() function. I have code in the ajax function's error method to handle ajax timeouts (see code below), and everything works fine in Firefox. But in IE, I get the following message: "The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available."

Before I go any further, here's my code:

```
error: function(xhr, status) {

    var res = xhr.responseText;
    var err = null;

    if (res && res.charAt(0) == '{')
        err = $.secureEvalJSON(res);
    if (!err) {
        if (status == "timeout") {
            err = new CallbackException("The request has timed out.");
        }
        else if (xhr.status != 200) {
            err = new CallbackException(xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
        else {
            err = new CallbackException("Unknown Error Response");
        }

        err.detail = res;
    }
    else
        err = new CallbackException(err); // force error to common format

    if (errorHandler)
        errorHandler(err, _I, xhr);
    }
}
```

So you can see, the first thing I do in an error situation, is check `xhr.responseText`. In Firefox, this string is empty (`""`), but in IE, it's "The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available". Even referencing the `responseText` value of `xhr` in IE throws an error, and the user gets an error dialog.

I've read in a couple places that I should wait until `xhr.readyState == 4` until I reference `xhr.responseText`, but if I put an `if (xhr.readyState == 4) {` block around the code in my error function, it never runs in an ajax timeout case. When I inspect the `readyState` property, its value is `1`, which I think is "loading".

Is this normal for an ajax timeout? Will the ready state ever be 4? If not, how can I ever reference xhr.responseText without IE blowing up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have read that you need to change your code to check that
 typeof(xhr.responseText) != 'unknown')
I haven't confirmed that it works yet because its hard to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, that seems to work. Important detail: the type you're checking against is *unknown* not the usual *undefined*.